# Interactions in Cox proportional hazard model : issue between contrasts and two categorical factors

Tags: r, categorical-data, survival-analysis, interaction, cox-regression

I need help in order to understand how the coxph() function in R works, thus how to interprete CORRECTLY the output.

I try to run a cox proportional hazard model on a 'survival analysis' data set with two factors : Sex and Genotype.
The Sex factor has two categorical variables: "m" for males and "f" for females.
The Genotype factor has three categorical variables: "Ctrl", "nKO", "CRE_Ctrl".
I want to see if there is an interaction, therefore I have done:

```
library(survival)
Survival = Surv(time = D$Age, event = D$outcome) #D is my dataframe, Age is time of death, outcome is the column for censored individuals.
```

Besides, I want to also see the following contrasts: "nKO vs Ctrl", and "nKO vs CRE_Ctrl". Thus I have set nKO as the baseline for my contrasts using this line:

```
D$Genotype = relevel(D$Genotype, ref = "nKO")
colnames(contrasts(D$Genotype)) = c(' (nKO vs CRE_Ctrl)', ' (nKO vs Ctrl)')
```

So, in the end, I run this final line:

```
coxph(data = mydata, formula = Survival ~ Sex * Genotype)
```

The output looks like this:

```
                                   coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z        p
Sexm                            -0.5769    0.5616   0.2294 -2.514 0.011925
Genotype (nKO vs CRE_Ctrl)      -0.9983    0.3685   0.2593 -3.850 0.000118
Genotype (nKO vs Ctrl)          -0.4072    0.6655   0.2461 -1.654 0.098034
Sexm:Genotype (nKO vs CRE_Ctrl)  0.5940    1.8111   0.3483  1.705 0.088147
Sexm:Genotype (nKO vs Ctrl)      0.5607    1.7520   0.3444  1.628 0.103539
```

OK, so it seems that I have all I want.
However, I have noticed one thing ! When I change the baseline for the Sex factor as 'm' instead of 'f' as above, I obtain a different output:

```
D$Sex = relevel(D$Sex, ref = "m")
coxph(data = D, formula = Survival ~ Sex * Genotype)

                                   coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z      p
Sexf                             0.5769    1.7805   0.2294  2.514 0.0119
Genotype (nKO vs CRE_Ctrl)      -0.4044    0.6674   0.2438 -1.658 0.0972
Genotype (nKO vs Ctrl)           0.1536    1.1660   0.2406  0.638 0.5232
Sexf:Genotype (nKO vs CRE_Ctrl) -0.5940    0.5521   0.3483 -1.705 0.0881
Sexf:Genotype (nKO vs Ctrl)     -0.5607    0.5708   0.3444 -1.628 0.1035
```

You can see that I have the oposite output for Sexf, Sexf:Genotype (nKO vs CRE_Ctrl), and Sexf:Genotype (nKO vs Ctrl), which I understand. But not for Genotype (nKO vs CRE_Ctrl), Genotype (nKO vs Ctrl), which I do not understand.
So, I don't understand what is going on here. Why do my contrasts for the Genotype factor without interactions seem to be affected by the baseline from the Sex factor ? Indeed, you can even see that the p values are significant with 'f' as the baseline (first coxph output) for my genotype contrasts, whereas the p values are not significant when 'm' is the baseline (second coxph output)... So, which one to trust ?

Can you explain me why is this happening please ? It is my first survival analysis, and I might be ignorant about many things regarding this type of analyses.

Thanks in advance for your responses,

Answer (score 4):

You are making a common mistake. The interpretation of model predictions for interaction models should not focus on interpretation of main effects. (Unfortunately this fact is not understood by many teachers of statistics and it's quite common to hear even experienced users of statistics trying to talk about the meaning of main effects coefficients in interaction terms.) There is no "contrasts for the Genotype factor without interactions", although there would be in a non-interaction model. Because you built an interaction model, the Genotype coefficients can only be interpreted by simultaneously specifying one Sex or the other.  You should instead be focusing on predictions and comparisons of particular combination of variables. That is what an interaction model implies, i.e. that you need to know both variables at once. You really have 6 distinct possible situations, so when you choose a new reference situation then it should not be a surprise that the relative risks compared to the new reference all change.

The Sex coefficients are implicitly paired with the same reference level of the Genotype variable. That's what allows the absolute values to be the same. In the case of nKO vs CRE_Ctrl notice that  -0.4044  -0.5940 equals -0.9984 which is the same as -0.9983 up to rounding error. And for Genotype (nKO vs Ctrl);  -0.4072 + 0.5607 is equal to 0.1536 up to rounding error. You are looking at the same differences on the log scale but from "different perspectives".

If we had data to work with we could illustrate this better by doing so predictions.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. Here is my dataframe available on Github: https://github.com/CroixJeremy2/Data-frame-for-stack-overflow. So you can illustrate better as you mentionned. So, as far as I understood, I can't have access to the contrasts for the Genotype factor when I run a model with interaction. So, what should I do? Run a model without interaction in order to get access to the contrasts, and then run a model with interaction in order to see the interactions ? You said "predictions and comparisons of particular combination of variables", can you explain me what that would be ?

Comment: Do you know a link or a webpage where I could learn more about this type of analysis using coxph() with models that include interactions and contrasts ? Because, I have the feeling that I don't understand everything, and that the topic is complex, thus I am worried to not interprete my data correctly...

Comment: You might start with https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-test-contrasts-in-r/ .  One SE forum that is more aligned with your hopes of an explanation of the connection between output and theory is CrossValidated.com. I have often recommended Frank Harrell's "Regression Modeling Strategies" for people who want more in depth treatment of theory, although I cannot recall whether this topic is specifically handled in detail.